# Word separation from a word (Regex & PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I've created the following regex code to find and separate the initial capital letter in a word.

```
 $string = "hello worldB. What are you doing now";
 $string = "hello worldB.What are you doing now"; // variant 2
 $clean = preg_replace('/[a-z0-9]+(?:[A-Z].+)/', '? ', $string);
```

There's a regex error. Can you help me?

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BKo5D8/1)

Comment: Try `$s = preg_replace('~[a-z0-9](?=[A-Z]\.)~', '$0 ', $s)`. See https://regex101.com/r/jmlaqg/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This message has been accepted. Thank you Wiktor!

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex, the dot is not escaped and matches any chars other than line break chars. Also, `(?:[A-Z].+)` is a non-capturing group and its pattern is *consuming*. You either need a capturing group and then replacement should contain a backreference to that group, or a lookahead, a non-consuming pattern.

You may use

```
$s = preg_replace('~[a-z0-9](?=[A-Z]\.)~', '$0 ', $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jmlaqg/1).

**Details**

- `[a-z0-9]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[A-Z]\.)` - (a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) that is followed with an uppercase ASCII letter and a dot.

Note that `$0` is a placeholder for the whole match value found by the regex.

Comment: A comma or semicolon instead of dot? Multiple is possible?

Comment: @J.Doe3 To match either `,` or `.` use `[.,]`. To match any punctuation, use either `[[:punct:]]` or `\p{P}`. Add  `+` to these patterns to match one or more occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that we might need an space before it, which we can do that using:

```
([a-z])([A-Z])
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/sj3BHK/1/)

Here, if possible, we won't bound it from the right.

#### Test

```
$re = '/([a-z])([A-Z])/m';
$str = 'hello worldB. What are you doing now
hello worldB.What are you doing now
';
$subst = '$1 $2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

If we wish to just capture that, we could just use this simple expression:

```
[a-z]([A-Z])
```

or

```
[a-z]([A-Z])\.
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Yfse5J/1)

#### Test

```
$re = '/[a-z]([A-Z])/m';
$str = 'hello worldB. What are you doing now
hello worldB.What are you doing now
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Yfse5J/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have not limited the amount of times the group has to repeat. If you want to find the **first** occurrence of a capital letter in a sentence you can use the following regex:

```
[a-z0-9]+([A-Z]{1})
```

This will match the first capital letter found in the sentence that repeated ***exactly*** one time with `{1}`. This is called a *fixed quantifier*, read more about regex quantifier in general [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html).

See the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/BKo5D8/2).

However if all you wanted was to find the first **capital** letter you should use a more inclusive regex that will match whitespaces, special characters and other stuff:

```
.*([A-Z]{1}).*
```

See the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/7uuKQr/1).